# Return Title of Closest Feature (json) Polygon using Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, geolocation, leaflet

I have four outlines (features) in json format that show as polygons on a leaflet map. Currently I am showing my current location when clicking on the L.Control.Locate arrow. It shows me near the polygon, however, I'd like to know which polygon (by title) I am closest to and have an alert or at least a variable tell me the title of the nearest.

Using Next Nearest https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn, I am not clear on how to get the closest point. I created a small function:

```
function nearBy(latlng){
    //does nearBy() have the latlng? This does show me the latlng of the user
    alert(latlng);
    //pass in all the data
    var gj = L.geoJson(GEOJSON_DATA);
    //do the knn magics
    var index = leafletKnn(gj).nearest(L.latLng(latlng), 5);
    //show me something
    alert(index);
}
```

alert(index) is spewing out: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

...which is great, cause it is showing that something is there, however, I cannot get anything other than that.

Anyone out there using leaflet-knn to do such as I am?

... EDIT ... 
json looks like so (not complete below):

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "<a href='framework/index.html'><h3>Conecuh National Forest</h3></a>", "description": "<html xmlns:fo=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/XSL\/Format\" xmlns:msxsl=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt\">\n\n<head>\n\n<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text\/html\">\n\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text\/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n\n<\/head>\n\n<body style=\"margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;\">\n\n<table style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px\">\n\n<tr style=\"text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2\">\n\n<td>Conecuh National Forest<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>\n\n<table style=\"font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px\">\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>PROCLAIMEDFORESTID<\/td>\n\n<td>295366010328<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>FORESTNAME<\/td>\n\n<td>Conecuh National Forest<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>GIS_ACRES<\/td>\n\n<td>171215.333<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>SHAPE<\/td>\n\n<td>Polygon<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr>\n\n<td>SHAPE.AREA<\/td>\n\n<td>0.065501<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<tr bgcolor=\"#D4E4F3\">\n\n<td>SHAPE.LEN<\/td>\n\n<td>1.596221<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<\/table>\n\n<\/td>\n\n<\/tr>\n\n<\/table>\n\n<\/body>\n\n<\/html>", "timestamp": null, "begin": null, "end": null, "altitudeMode": null, "tessellate": 1, "extrude": -1, "visibility": -1, "drawOrder": null, "icon": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -86.399549, 31.205536, 0.0 ], [ -86.407326, 31.205638, 0.0 ], [ -86.409808, 31.205671, 0.0 ], [ -86.413319, 31.205717, 0.0 ], [ -86.414067, 31.205711, 0.0 ], [ -86.418361, 31.205674, 0.0 ], [ -86.429486, 31.20558, 0.0 ], [ -86.429544, 31.198715, 0.0 ], [ -86.429615, 31.190445, 0.0 ], [ -86.429627, 31.185575, 0.0 ], [ -86.429651, 31.175982, 0.0 ], [ -86.430013, 31.175979, 0.0 ], [ -86.430563, 31.175974, 0.0 ], [ -86.432963, 31.175952, 0.0 ], [ -86.433052, 31.175951, 0.0 ], [ -86.433474, 31.175947, 0.0 ], [ -86.433864, 31.175944, 0.0 ]
```

... EDIT 2 ...

Using FireBug and console.log() i was able to get to the results. Leaflet-knn returns them correctly, having the closest LatLng as (in my json) index[0].lat + "," index[0].lon

I'd still love some examples of "clean" ways of doing this if anyone has one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nearestLayer` instead of `nearest`: this will return the nearest layer instead of the nearest point, as specified in the documentation.

Comment: I am not sure i understand the difference. If I get the nearest point in the polygon, isn't that the same as getting the nearest layer?

Comment: Maybe nearestLayer is faster? with the whole collapse of points matched?

Comment: If you're trying to get a _feature_ (as in the title of this question), then you should use `nearestLayer`, because it will return a Polygon. If you want the nearest _point_, then use `nearest`.